# retrieve multidimension array data

Tags: php, arrays

How to retrieve the data from array like this :

```
$module =  array(array ( [module_id] => 1 ),
                 array ( [module_id] => 2 ),
                 array ( [module_id] => 3 ), 
                 array ( [module_id] => 4 ),
                 array ( [module_id] => 5 )
                );
```

I just want to retrieve the value (1,2,3,4 or 5) and save to string variable

Comment: Your syntax to array is wrong.

Comment: i got that data from print_r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$module =  array(array ( 'module_id' => 1 ),
               array ( 'module_id' => 2 ),
               array ( 'module_id' => 4 ), 
               array ( 'module_id' => 5 ), 
               array ( 'module_id' => 6 ));

$string = '';
foreach($module as $mod) {
    $string .= $mod['module_id'].',';
}
$string = substr($string,0,-1);

echo $string;
```

Comment: i want to save to some variable

Comment: Have you tried something to save in variable ? Please post in your question

Comment: I have updated the code. Check if you want the string like that